# How to convert ticks to datetime in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

How to convert ticks to datetime in Python?

I am trying to convert 52707330000 to 1 hour and 27 minutes and 50 seconds.

Somehow it works here - http://tickstodatetime.com/. I tried inspecting the element but I don't understand javascript.

Comment: You could divide by 543374536.0824742... Or 605831379.3103448, depending on whether you want 97 seconds or 1 minute 27 seconds (i.e. 87 seconds)

Comment: What are 'ticks' in this context? How does `52707330000` translate to 1 minute and 27 seconds? Or 97 seconds (which is a different value altogether again).

Comment: I'm not sure what the ticks are in this context. I know somehow it works in the website that converts ticks to seconds which I pasted above in the description. And sorry for the typo it is 87 seconds.

Comment: The website is reporting 52707330000 ticks equals 1 hour, 27 minutes, 50.734 seconds NOT 1 minute 27 seconds... So 10**7 ticks = 1 second.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following will convert the ticks to a Python datetime object (from now) using datetime's timedelta.

```
import datetime
ticks = 52707330000
converted_ticks = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(microseconds = ticks/10)
```

Then something like:

```
converted_ticks.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") // '2015-08-07 14:17:48'
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Using just `datetime.timedelta(microseconds = ticks/10)` will give you the time, not relative to "now".

Answer (score 7):

To get the same time as on the web-site:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ticks = 52707330000
dt = datetime(1, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=ticks/10)
print(dt.isoformat() + "Z")
# -> 0001-01-01T01:27:50.733000Z
```

Comment: For Microsoft 'ticks' given for things like pwdLastSet, the above code works great, except Microsoft uses the year 1601 as the starting date.  So the datetime line above would be: dt = datetime(1601, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=ticks / 10)

Answer (score 6):

You could just use:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 52707330000
your_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

or not?